# Vim not working without sudo via ssh

Tags: ssh, sudo, users, vim

I can no longer use `vim` on my server via `ssh` without the `sudo` prefix.

commands that failed silently (never end) :

```
touch foo   # works fine: I do have writing permissions in that folder
vim foo     # fail
vim         # fail
```

everything works with :

```
sudo vim foo
sudo vim
```

Comment: Fails how? What does the computer say when you type `vim foo`? I know of several approaches to more specific versions of this problem, but cannot know which would apply without more information.

Comment: Commands are just running endlessly with no output at all. I found a workaround, as described in my answer below. I'm still interested in a explanation : why does `sudo vim` works when `vim` doesn't, with X11 forwarding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here was the issue :

I was logged with `ssh -Y` option, which enable `trusted X11 forwarding`, as described in `man ssh` :

```
 -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not
         subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls

         (Debian-specific: This option does nothing in the default configuration:
         it is equivalent to “ForwardX11Trusted yes”, which is the default as
         described above.  Set the ForwardX11Trusted option to “no” to restore
         the upstream behaviour.This may hange in future depending on client-side
         improvements.)
```

Connecting without that option solved it somehow.